# ERRO[0000] Error fetching api: no Auth Provider found for name "gcp" -- GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to install kubeye am getting the below error:

```
./ke install npd

ERRO[0000] Error fetching api: no Auth Provider found for name "gcp"
Failed to create configmap: no Auth Provider found for name "gcp"

Installing kubeeye: https://github.com/kubesphere/kubeeye/releases --
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What GKE version are you using? What you want to do/achieve? Are you using any guide/tutorial?

Comment: GKE version 1.18

Comment: Trying to launch kubeeye on GKE cluster ./ke diag will show the health status of cluster

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to run [kubeeye](https://github.com/kubesphere/kubeeye) on `GKE`. To run `kubeeye` you must have access to `Master` and in `GKE` master is managed by `Google` so you won't have access to it. I think that `GKE` monitoring tools also provides similar functionality.

However, you can use `kubeeye` on `Google Compute Engine` where you can run some `VMs` and create [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) cluster.

```
$ wget https://github.com/kubesphere/kubeeye/releases/download/v0.1.0/KubeEye-v0.1.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xzvf KubeEye-v0.1.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz

$ ./ke install npd
Installing NPD ...
Installation is successful. 

$ ./ke diag
ERRO[0000] Cache missed Installation/calico-system/default again 

NAME                 SEVERITY   TIME                   MESSAGE
scheduler            Fatal      2021-03-10T13:53:23Z   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: connect: connection refused
controller-manager   Fatal      2021-03-10T13:53:23Z   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: connect: connection refused

NAMESPACE       SEVERITY   PODNAME                                                     EVENTTIME              REASON      MESSAGE
calico-system   Warning    calico-kube-controllers-6797d7cc89-9z68l.166afecf38ee349e   2021-03-10T13:39:42Z   Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: 
calico-system   Warning    calico-typha-7cfcbbf67-xk2kg.166afebf69f9bc87               2021-03-10T13:38:34Z   Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: Get "http://localhost:9098/readiness": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9098: connect: connection refused
calico-system   Warning    calico-typha-7cfcbbf67-xk2kg.166afec031b30286               2021-03-10T13:38:37Z   Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed: Get "http://localhost:9098/liveness": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9098: connect: connection refused
default         Warning    liveness-http.166ab3f5b34b41de
```

Just as additional informaton, in `itnext` article [KubeEye: An Automatic Diagnostic Tool that Provides a Holistic View of Your Kubernetes Cluster](https://itnext.io/kubeeye-an-automatic-diagnostic-tool-that-provides-a-holistic-view-of-your-kubernetes-cluster-badcb1a3ba59) you can find comment from google engineer which pointing that `kubeeye` is useless on `GKE`.